# AWN dock doesn't differentiate the active window

Tags: dock, awn

I have installed Avant Window Navigator 0.4.1 in Ubuntu 12.10 (64 bit) and am pretty much satisfied with its looks. But one thing that is lacking is, it **fails to differentiate the current or active window** on the dock. Everything looks the same.

As shown in the screen-shot below, I use multiple profiles in firefox and open multiple instances of firefox and get confused between which window I am currently working with.

[image]

Is there any way to highlight the active window  in awn?

Answer (score 1):

I found a setting under awn theme customization called `Active Rectangle` which was exactly what I was looking for. After changing that setting to my need, I was able to see a rectangle on the active window icon. Below is the screen-shot.
[image]